# make a file that will run in cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

is it possible to make a file that when double clicked, it will run "ping 8.8.8.8 -t" to Windows Command Prompt automatically.
so  dont need to "Windows+R > ping 8.8.8.8 -t > enter" to do that

do i need a compiler to do that?

Comment: Please do some research before you ask here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, make a `.bat` file with your text editor (the flat text one) and paste the command in that file. Such as:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 -t
```

Be sure to save it as `.bat` and not as `.txt`.

Comment: Well instead of saying, "it ruined your experience".
You also could suggest the correct grammer.

Comment: Oh, sorry. The start of sentences need a capital letter, and you need a full stop after every sentence.

Comment: I thought you were just one of those people that can't be bothered to use correct grammar. No hard feelings?

Comment: Only if you tell me wich mistake i made, and how to solve it ;)